# Does Im$(T)\cap$Ker$(T)={0}$ implies $T^2=T$, where $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$, $V$ is finite dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I know that in a finite dimensional vector space $V$ if $T^2=T$, then $\operatorname{Im}(T)\cap\operatorname{Ker}(T)={0}$, where $T:V\to V$ is linear map. But my question is- **Does the converse true?**
My intuition says that the answer is NO. Even I can prove if $\operatorname{Im}(T)\cap\operatorname{Ker}(T)={0}$ then $\operatorname{Rank}(T^2)=\operatorname{Rank}(T)$.
***If the answer is NO, can anybody give an example where $\operatorname{Im}(T)\cap\operatorname{Ker}(T)={0}$ but $T^2\ne T$?***
Thanks for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $T(x)=2x$, $kerT=0$, $imT=V$, where $dimV\geq 1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\dim V$?